# Customizing web services endpoint(URL) across sandbox/PROD orgs

Tags: apex, webservices

I am calling a external web service via APEX and it is working fine..However the endpoint(URL) is hard coded in the code and it would be different when I migrate the code to QA sandbox..How can customize the URL? I am thinking of using Custom Settings approach and store the URL as custom setting. Is this the right approach? would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used custom settings for this, and it works well. I store the host name separate from the paths. This has the additional advantage that you can switch to endpoints on different environments fast.

Edit to add this example:

I use a ServiceCenterConfig__c list custom setting with two fields (Name, Value__c) to store general configuration information for an application.
One record is `[name="msc server", value__c="https://production.server.com"]`, another is `[name="msc path", value__c="/path/to/rest/endpoint"]`.
In a sandbox, I can set `"msc server"` to another value, e. g. `"https://staging.server.com"`. The `"msc path"` record stays the same for all environments.

This way, I can connect a sandbox to the same web service on a different environment than my production org. You could connect your UAT or integration sandbox to a staging or integration environment of the web service.

But since it's Summer '17 already, I would recommend to look into custom metadata instead of custom settings to do this.

Comment: i'd love an example of this

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update...any resources on how one would accomplish this using custom metadata? As the only problem the original answer has i copying prod down to a sandbox will constantly have people updating the server address

Comment: Using custom metadata would look very much alike. Just substitute the list custom setting with a custom metadata type. 
Yes, updating the server address is necessary after a sandbox refresh.  But you can automate this with a SandboxPostCopy class: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with above.  I use custom settings to stash the URL and associated environment (Stage/Prod), then I use the following code (originally found on SE) to detect the environment executing the code:

```
public static Boolean isSandboxInstance()
{
    String s  =  System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost();
    return (Pattern.matches('(.*\\.)?cs[0-9]*(-api)?\\..*force.com',s)) ? true : false;
}
```